# Linux delete line do not delete Maximum value

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a question control txt file.

one txt file contain below example structure
delimited by tab (\t)
And it's already sorted by Name , desc Score, desc Length

```
Name  Score  Length

Test1    500   400
Test1    499   400
Test1    499   399
Test1    498   100
Test2    600   200
Test2    600   199
Test2    599   199
```

I want to delete line without top line of Name
For example as below

```
Name  Score  Length

Test1    500   400
Test2    600   200
```

Anyone have a good Idea to figure it out?
Awk or Sed ..

Thank you for your any information!

Comment: `rev file | uniq -f 2 | rev`, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your file is already sorted, this `awk` makes it:

```
$ awk '!a[$1]++' file
Name  Score  Length

Test1    500   400
Test2    600   200
```

This keeps track of what first fields have appeared. Once they appear, their index gets incremented and hence any line starting with that value appears again.

A longer version, not that much idiomatic, could be:

```
awk '{if (a[$1]) next; a[$1]++} 1' file
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much it's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: if I do -> awk '!a[$1]++' file > file  then there are delete all file content do you no how to paste with same name?

Comment: @fedorqui Could you please explain what the exclamation mark does within `awk`?

Comment: @clear.choi never try to write to the same file you are reading from as the shell can zap the file first and THEN open it for reading. Use a tmp file instead, e.g. `awk '!a[$1]++' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. @skamazin - `!` is just the `not` conditional operator. @fedorqui your second version is much worse than the first, if I were you I'd remove it.

Comment: @skamazin the `!` negates conditions. So for example `awk '$2'` will print the lines of the file whose 2nd column is not 0, while `awk '!$2'` will do the opposite.